# Is it possible to use a proxy/vpn just for one software?

Tags: networking, vpn, pandora

I've recently discovered Pandora and i love it 
But i'm Belgian so i have to use a vpn to listen to pandora

At school i have internet constraint (like i can't go on youtube, facebook,...) and i'm already bypassing it with a vpn on France

But i don't want to use a vpn on U.s for all my software 'cuz it makes the connection really slow

So 'im asking if on windows 10, i can just fake my location for the Pandora software but not for the rest of my software

exemple: Discord (that is not accesible at school) think that i'm france as i use my vpn for that
and at the same time Pandora think that i'm in the U.s so that i can use it

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe this post will have some very detailed responses on your question.
[Use a VPN for selected applications only](https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-applications)